# C pointer address is very strange

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Sorry for my poor English, I have written the C code for Splaying tree, but when I put the "Find()" operation in main function, I couldn't initialize the Tree, that is, without the line "Find()" , using GDB, I found the my_tree's value is "0x0" when breakpoint in line "MakeEmpty", but add the line "Find", the value is "0x7fffffffbeb0". I know the Find() function has problem, but I don't understand why the latter statements infect the former statement?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "SPTree.c"

void main()
{
    Position my_tree;

    my_tree = MakeEmpty( my_tree );

    my_tree = Insert( 5, my_tree );
    my_tree = Insert( 6, my_tree );

    Position P = Find( 5, &my_tree );
}
```

Here is the statement

```
struct SPNode;
typedef struct SPNode *Position;
typedef struct SPNode *SPTree;
typedef int ElementType;
```

and the tree node

```
struct SPNode
{
    ElementType Element;
    SPTree Left;
    SPTree Right;
};
```

This is the Insert

```
SPTree Insert( ElementType X, SPTree tree )
{
    if( tree == NULL )
    {
        //此时 tree 是一棵空树，分配空间并创建一棵树
        tree = malloc( sizeof( struct SPNode ) );
        if( tree == NULL )
            printf("Out of space!!!\n");
        else
        {
            tree->Element = X;
            tree->Left = tree->Right = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //递归插入 X 到合适的子树中
        if( X < tree->Element )
            tree->Left = Insert( X, tree->Left );
        else if( X > tree->Element )
            tree->Right = Insert( X, tree->Right );
        else
            //X已经在树中，什么也不做
            ;
    }
    return tree;
}
```

and this is the Find at my github repo(for it's too long): https://github.com/hengyicai/Find/blob/master/Find.c

What I confused is : when the main function like this

```
void main()
{
    Position my_tree;  //line 1

    my_tree = MakeEmpty( my_tree );

    my_tree = Insert( 5, my_tree );
    my_tree = Insert( 6, my_tree );

}
```

I debug for breakpoint at line 1,and print the value of my_tree is 0x0 as below

please see here: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hengyicai/Find/master/" please see the Pic_1.png.

but after add the Find() finction to the main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "SPTree.c"

void main()
{
    Position my_tree;

    my_tree = MakeEmpty( my_tree );

    my_tree = Insert( 5, my_tree );
    my_tree = Insert( 6, my_tree );

    Position P = Find( 5, &my_tree );
}
```

I get the value of my_tree like this: please see the Pic_2.png in the above link.

why the value of my_tree different from the previous, just add the Find() to the last line?

Comment: without the code for the other functions it's hard to say

Comment: 0x7fffffffbeb0: looks like it's allocated in the stack, but it's hard to say. Try `int x; printf("%p",&x);` -- it will give you an address in the stack

Comment: Why do you need the address-of `&` for `Find()` but not for `Insert()`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect the `Find` operation to modify the tree? It ought to rotate the tree to bring the element 5 to the root, which obviously involves modifications. That's the whole point of a splay tree after all.

Comment: @Weather Vane: Presumably to be able to return NULL in case of failure while still rotating the tree. The insertions don't have this problem, unless they need to indicate out-of-memory conditions anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MakeEmpty()` function return a pointer or a Value?

The code are very strange. 
I suppose that `MakeEmpty()` could return a pointer to an empty `Position` structure.

Normally you can choose 2 way, for return a pointer from a function:

1 - Retrieve the pointer as passing parameter;

2 - Retrieve the pointer as return value;

```
typedef foo_t;

foo_t foo;


pass_bar(foo_t **pass_foo)
{

    ...
    //Set the pointer to the **pass_foo parameter
} 


foo_t* return_foo(void)
{
   foo_t *my_foo;

   //Set the pointer my_foo to a valid memory address for foo_t 
   ...
   return my_foo;
}
```

You have added the tag `pointers`, but in this piece of code you don't use any pointer...

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  sorry for my poor expression, I add the Find and Insert Code to this problem.

Comment: After the edit...
I don't know `MakeEmpty`, but `Insert`, in case of NULL pointer passed as `tree`, return a pointer to a memory location of a `tree` structure with only one element. No other element are added...
Then, in the two next function calls you modify only the `tree->Right` value of the _same_ structure. Calling the function `Find()`, the function checks that `tree->Left` is NULL an then return NULL